# TypeScript add object to array with spread

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm trying to be cute with TypeScript and arrays and use the spread operator to essentially prepend an object to an array of objects.

Here's the setup:

Interface to define my types:

```
interface KeyValuePair {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
```

An array of objects of type:

```
const kvpset: KeyValuePair[] = [
  { key: "1", value: "One" },
  { key: "2", value: "Two" },
  { key: "3", value: "Three" },
  { key: "4", value: "Four" },
  { key: "5", value: "Five" },
  { key: "6", value: "Six" },
  { key: "7", value: "Seven" },
  { key: "8", value: "Eight" },
  { key: "9", value: "Nine" },
];
```

My prepend typed object thingy:

```
const kvpzero: KeyValuePair = { key: "0", value: "Zero" };
```

First try:

```
const kvpAll: KeyValuePair[] = { kvpzero, ...kvpset };
```

Error in the editor:

> property) kvpzero: KeyValuePair Type '{ length: number; toString():
> string; toLocaleString(): string; pop(): KeyValuePair; push(...items:
> KeyValuePair[]): number; concat(...items:
> ConcatArray[]): KeyValuePair[]; concat(...items:
> (KeyValuePair | ConcatArray<...>)[]): KeyValuePair[]; ... 26 more ...;
> kvpzero: KeyValuePair; }' is not assignable to type 'KeyValuePair[]'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'kvpzero' does
> not exist in type 'KeyValuePair[]'.ts(2322)

Okay, so I'm a bit clueless. I'll try this:

```
const kvpzeroAsArray: KeyValuePair[] = [{ key: "0", value: "Zero" }];
```

and this doesn't give a "compiler error":

```
const kvpAll: KeyValuePair[] = { ...kvpzeroAsArray, ...kvpset };
```

Using tsc and node to run it (editor is Visual Studio Code). Results in a console.log() for the kvpAll object:

```
kvpAll is {
  '0': { key: '1', value: 'One' },
  '1': { key: '2', value: 'Two' },
  '2': { key: '3', value: 'Three' },
  '3': { key: '4', value: 'Four' },
  '4': { key: '5', value: 'Five' },
  '5': { key: '6', value: 'Six' },
  '6': { key: '7', value: 'Seven' },
  '7': { key: '8', value: 'Eight' },
  '8': { key: '9', value: 'Nine' }
}
```

Three things that I see here. One, the object is now an object and not an array. Two, my zero is missing.I have no idea why this doesn't work or why I can't get the expected results. Three, it's not even the same type of output I wanted. It has the property as a number with the value as the object. `'0': { key: '1', value: 'One' }` instead of just `{ key: '1', value: 'One' }`.

Searching on the web, it seems that maybe the `Object.assign()` mechanism is a way to go.

```
const assignedkvp = (<any>Object).assign(kvpzeroAsArray, kvpset);
```

Output (via a `console.log()` again):

```
assignedkvp is [
  { key: '1', value: 'One' },
  { key: '2', value: 'Two' },
  { key: '3', value: 'Three' },
  { key: '4', value: 'Four' },
  { key: '5', value: 'Five' },
  { key: '6', value: 'Six' },
  { key: '7', value: 'Seven' },
  { key: '8', value: 'Eight' },
  { key: '9', value: 'Nine' }
]
```

Hmm...similar results as the spread. The object doesn't get changed as the spread changes it, but I still don't see my desired pretending result.

I'm at a loss at this point. I don't understand how I can use the spread operator or the assign function and get the desired results. I'd appreciate any insight. Here's my current solution. The brute force method:

```
const prePendObjectToArray = <T>(object: T, array: T[]): T[] => {
  let returnArray = [] as T[];

  if (array && array.length > 0 && object) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length + 1; i++) {
      if (i === 0) {
        returnArray.push(object);
      } else {
        returnArray.push(array[i - 1]);
      }
    }
  }

  return returnArray;
};
```

Usage:

```
const newArray = prePendObjectToArray(kvpzero, kvpset);
console.log(newArray);
```

Result:

```
[
  { key: '0', value: 'Zero' },
  { key: '1', value: 'One' },
  { key: '2', value: 'Two' },
  { key: '3', value: 'Three' },
  { key: '4', value: 'Four' },
  { key: '5', value: 'Five' },
  { key: '6', value: 'Six' },
  { key: '7', value: 'Seven' },
  { key: '8', value: 'Eight' },
  { key: '9', value: 'Nine' }
]
```

If there is a better way, I'd appreciate knowing what I'm missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const kvpAll: KeyValuePair[] = { ...kvpzeroAsArray, ...kvpset };
```

This is not an array. You are spreading into an object.

Do:

```
const kvpAll: KeyValuePair[] = [ ...kvpzeroAsArray, kvpset ];
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking I was missing something simple, and I was. That resolved my issue.