# "Spread operator" syntax

Tags: typescript

I have this base type:

```
export interface IMyType : {
   field1: number,
   field2: number
}
```

I also have this "extension" type:

```
export interface ISelectable {
   isSelected: boolean;
}
```

Somewhere else, I have a function like this:

```
const foo = (param: (IMyType & ISelectable)[]) => { // <-- my on-the-fly "extended" type
   param[0].isSelected = ... //do whatever
}
```

My problem is to created the composite array:

```
const dataArray: IMyType[] = [{field1: 0, field2: 0}, {field1: 0, field2: 0}];
const extendedArray = [ dataArray, ...[{isSelected: false}] ]; // <-- extend!

foo(extendedArray); // <-- PROBLEM! typescript still sees extendedArray
                    //     as of type IMyType[] instead of 
                    //    (IMyType & Iselectable)[]  so it refuses this.
```

I'm 99% sure that I misused the spread operator (`...`) but right now I can't find the right syntax.

In recap, I tried the following :

```
const extendedArray = [ dataArray, ...[{isSelected: false}] ]; //Nope! (Makes zero sense, in the light of the comments below)
const extendedArray = [ ...dataArray, {isSelected: false} ]; //nope! (Makes zero sense, in the light of the comments below)
const extendedarray = dataArray.map (x => {isSelected: false, ...x}) //Almost correct but was missing sone syntactic sugar!
```

I've read this and many other answers but I can't figure it out : [TypeScript add object to array with spread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64591508/typescript-add-object-to-array-with-spread)

Comment: What value were you expecting to get? You add one value to the end of the array, equivalent to push, so the result is  an array of the _union_ not the intersection of those two types.

Comment: `[ dataArray, ...[{isSelected: false}] ];` means you have an array that contains *the full array* `dataArray` as one item, and then you also add *one item* to it which is `{isSelected: false}`. For example with `dataArray = [{field1: 1, field2: 11}, { field1: 2, field2: 22}]` you'd get the following array `[ [{field1: 1, field2: 11}, { field1: 2, field2: 22}], {isSelected: false} ]` It does not modify `dataArray` to add `{isSelected: false}` to each item. Moreover, that's not possible with spread (alone).

Comment: I want each item in the new array to be the same as the original array, but with extra field 'isSelected'

Comment: Well that's not at all what you're writing. Maybe use `.map` and spread each _object_.

Comment: "*I want each item in the new array to be the same as the original array, but with extra field 'isSelected'*" it's best to ask about that rather than [not that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: So I tried this and it's still not correct synctactically : const extendedarray = dataArray.map (x => {isSelected: false, ...x})

Comment: You need `()` around the object if you want to use the short body version of an arrow function: [ECMAScript 6 arrow function that returns an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28770415) `dataArray.map (x => {isSelected: false, ...x})` -> `dataArray.map (x => ({isSelected: false, ...x}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bu using the spread operateor you appened elements, you do not modify the existing ones

So
`const extendedArray = [ dataArray, ...[{isSelected: false}] ];`

The extendedArray will have two type elements:
First element will be an array of `IMyType` , the second element will be of type `{ isSelected: boolean }`

If you want to modify all elements in an array - use `.map()`. And preferably create a copy of all objects like this:

```js
const extendedArray = dataArray.map(item => { return { ...item, isSelected: false } });

//All is ok now
foo(extendedArray);
```

Playground  [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFkCeAVTAHFAbwFgAoZCmYCAGwBMBGALmRAFcBbAI2gBoyKyKrToAmFu27QyAXzJlQkWIhSoAyrQgIwcLjSICKwAM4b92iHRZcA9jf1wQAblnzSCGyGNghd5AF5kAAo8OCg4DhYgjBx8FAAyNDMtHT0IAEoAbQBddICAPmQSckEPL3sIADoaGwBzELCIzIAGbMqTZIs6dMMKOVIyMu9kOjgdAEEocMwWGNwCHIDkTMJhemZkZt4hanpxTZlt1d3GFi2dkX3mmWyXAfdPYYgAD0gQOktJ6aXRiam4TCVDhwPBBYCQDgFIrIKAQMBsKAgaGVFHgiAcbYdTRdFjwGjGFAyZAydJ3MgAenJ4xoNGQJmQNgA1qwbAB3MgwOxBF5vD50L4A0lkIA)

Comment: That's what I've been looking for. I failed because I thought this syntax was enough : ````const extendedarray = dataArray.map (x => {isSelected: false, ...x})```` but as some people have pointed out I need to add a few things : ```const extendedArray = dataArray.map(item => { return { ...item, isSelected: false } });```

Comment: @LouisWilke An answer that explains the problem and what it does to solve that problem is more valuable than a one-liner without any explanation at all.

Comment: @Andreas True. I guess I shall improve that in my next answers

Answer (score 1):

use spread operator

```
const extendedArray: (IMyType & ISelectable)[] = dataArray.map((el) => {
  return { ...el, isSelected: false };
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You can cast your array:

```js
const extendedArray = (dataArray as (IMyType&ISelectable)[]).map( d => {d.isSelected = false; return d} );
```

Comment: `dataArray` _isn't_ `(IMyType&ISelectable)[]`, you're lying to the compiler; it's the result of calling `.map` that is. This claims that `d` is already the right return value and you're just overwriting the _existing_ `isSelected` prop.